# How to pass a parameter to animation step functions?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I deconstructed an animation function into parts in the idea for them to be reusable:

```
const enterLeaveAnimation = (
  triggerName: string,
  step1: AnimationMetadata | AnimationMetadata[],
  step2: AnimationMetadata | AnimationMetadata[]
) =>
trigger(triggerName, [
  transition(':enter', step1, { params: { delay: 0 } }),
  transition(':leave', step2, { params: { delay: 0 } })
])

const fadeEnter = [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('600ms {{delay}}ms ease', style({ opacity: 1 }))]
const fadeLeave = [animate('600ms {{delay}}ms ease', style({ opacity: 0 }))]

const fadeAnimation = enterLeaveAnimation('fade', fadeEnter, fadeLeave);
```

`enterLeaveAnimation` is implemented as usual:

```
...
animations: [fadeAnimation],
```

and in the template:

```
<p @fade *ngIf="visible">
...
```

Everything seems to work as expected. The proof is in the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1hxcd?file=src/app/app.component.html).

However, I am unable to pass any `delay` value, which take 0 defined by default.

I tried:

```
...[@fade]="{value:true,params: {delay: 200}}"
```

that do not work and I don't know how to receive `delay` in the animation functions `fadeEnter` and `fadeLeave`.

The [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7ct47?file=src/app/app.component.html) of this attempt.

Also, my goal is to use two different delay values for each of steps. But first, I need to pass at lease one value.

How it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

The `params` should be added to the steps. It still will be set with default values, but it can also be received from the trigger:

```
const enterLeaveAnimation = (triggerName: string, step1: AnimationMetadata | AnimationMetadata[],
    step2: AnimationMetadata | AnimationMetadata[], params?: AnimationOptions | null | undefined
) =>
    trigger(triggerName, [
        transition(':enter', step1, params),
        transition(':leave', step2, params)
    ])

const fadeEnter = animation([style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('600ms {{delay1}}ms ease-out', style({ opacity: 1 }))], { params: { delay1: 0 } })
const fadeLeave = animation([animate('600ms {{delay2}}ms ease', style({ opacity: 0 }))], { params: { delay2: 0 } })
```

Usage:

```
...[@fade]="{value:true,params: {delay1: 200, delay2: 300}}"
```